# kafka data to elaticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to send data from apache kafka producer to elastic search using kafka connect elasticsearch

Getting following error in elasticsearch:

```
[2017-12-21T11:00:54,979][DEBUG][o.e.a.b.TransportShardBulkAction] 
[pageviews7][0] failed to execute bulk item (index) BulkShardRequest 
[[pageviews7][0]] containing [index {[pageviews7][kafkaconnect]
[pageviews7+0+0], source[{"key1":"value1"}]}]
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to find 
type parsed [string] for [key1]
```

Following is my kafka-connect-elasticsearch properties file:

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=
io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=pageviews7
key.ignore=true
connection.url=http://localhost:9200
type.name=kafkaconnect
schemas.enable=false
schema.ignore=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `stream-reactor` Kafka connectors for Elastic-Search. One uses the TCP protocol and the other one the HTTP protocol, and they have been battle-tested in Production sinking 5+ Billion events / day into ES indexes, and they are pretty easy to configure and well documented

https://github.com/landoop/stream-reactor

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with indexing the document into Elasticsearch:

1. Try to post your document into ES manually
2. You should get the same error. Which means you have some problem with your index mapping.
3. If the index has a problem with the mapping as I suspect, you can either write to another index using ***topic.index.map*** property or delete the current index (only if you don't care about the data).

**Example of how to curl manually into ES:**

```
curl -XPOST <ES-url>/pageviews7/test_id -d '{"key1":"value1"}'
```

**Delete you current inedex:**

```
curl -XDELETE <ES-url>/pageviews7
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Elasticsearch are you running? You may fine that setting `schema.ignore=true` in your Kafka Connect connector config will workaround this error.